# Getting all Ids that were inserted outside the transaction scope

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

Is it possible that after closing a transaction scope, we can obtain an array of ids containing all the ids inserted inside that transaction scope?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly don't profess to be the foremost expert on SQL (I've asked my share of sql questions on SO), but I've never heard of anything like this before. The only suggestions I have is to gather the IDs along the way, use an alternate key to identify the rows, or to not use incrementing ID fields and, instead, use unique identifiers (GUIDs).

Comment: I wish I could get the ids along the way but they return 0 after the command context.InsertOnSubmit(object);